# Remove empty bars from grouped barplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a grouped barplot. It's working very well, but I try to remove the empty barplots. They take too much space.

I have already tried :

```
%matplotlib inline
import os
import glob

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="pastel", color_codes=True)

tab_folder = 'myData'
out_folder = 'myData/plots'
tab = glob.glob('%s/R*.tab'%(tab_folder))

# is reading all my data
for i, tab_file in enumerate(tab):
    folder, file_name = os.path.split(tab_file)
    s_id = file_name[:-4].replace('DD', '')
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(tab_file, sep='\t')
    
    df_2 = df.groupby(['name', 'ab']).size().reset_index(name='count')
    df_2 = df_2[df_2['count'] != 0]
    
    table = pd.pivot_table(df_2, index='name',columns='ab', values='count' ) 
    table.plot(kind='barh', width = 0.9, color = ['b', 'g', 'r'], ax=ax)

    for label in (ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()):
        label.set_fontsize(4)
    
    ax.update({'color': 'black', 'size': 5, 'family': 'monospace'})
    ax.set(xlabel='', ylabel='', title=s_id)

    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    ax.legend(handles[::-1], labels[::-1], bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.05), prop={'size': 4})

png_t = '%s/%s.b.png'%(out_folder, s_id)
plt.savefig(png_t, dpi=500)
```

But it's not working. The bars are still the same.
Is there any other method to remove empty bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not complete. I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but from what you've said I'd guess that you are trying not to display empty pivot pairs.

This is not possible by standard means of pandas. Plot of groups need to display all of them even `NaNs` which will be plot as *"empty bars"*.

Furthermore after `groupby` every group is at least size of one, so `df_2[df_2['count'] != 0]` is allways true.

For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['nameA', 'abA'], ['nameB', 'abA'],['nameA','abB'],['nameD', 'abD']], columns=['names', 'ab'])
df_2 = df.groupby(['names', 'ab']).size().reset_index(name='count')
df_2 = df_2[df_2['count'] != 0] # this line has no effect
table = pd.pivot_table(df_2, index='names',columns='ab', values='count' ) 
table
```

gives

```
ab      abA     abB     abD
names           
nameA   1.00    1.00    NaN
nameB   1.00    NaN     NaN
nameD   NaN     NaN     1.00
```

and

```
table.plot(kind='barh', width = 0.9, color = ['b', 'g', 'r'])
```

shows

[image]

And that's the way it is. Plot need to show all groups after pivot.

**EDIT**

You can also use stacked plot, to get rid of spaces

```
table.plot(kind='barh', width = 0.9, color = ['b', 'g', 'r'], stacked=True)
```

[image: stacked]

Comment: Thank you for this example. But I still want to get rid of them. Do you now another way to remove them? I have also editted my code. Mayby that helps

Comment: Your code is not complete, as we do not know any data used.